# Como usar uma lista no Footer da ListView?

Tags: android

Adicionei um Footer *(rodapé)* numa ListView, porém esse Footer irá conter uma lista (`List<>`).

O Footer está aparecendo, porém está mostrando apenas o primeiro item da lista.

**Como fazer para mostrar corretamente a lista no Footer?**

### [Código exemplo no pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5dcbtr5S)

```
lvItens = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvItens);

List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
lista.add("Item 1");
lista.add("Item 2");
lista.add("Item 3");
lista.add("Item 4");
lista.add("Item 5");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista);

View viewFooter = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, null, false);

ListView lvItensFooter = (ListView) viewFooter.findViewById(R.id.lvItens);

List<String> listaFooter = new ArrayList<String>();
listaFooter.add("Footer 1");
listaFooter.add("Footer 2");
listaFooter.add("Footer 3");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapterFooter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaFooter);

lvItensFooter.setAdapter(adapterFooter);

lvItens.addFooterView(viewFooter);                      
lvItens.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[ListView-Footer http://felipearon.com.br/img/listview-footer.png](http://felipearon.com.br/img/listview-footer.png)

Comment: Poderia incluir o layout da sua `Activity` que contem este `ListView`? Você poderia reduzir o tamanho da imagem e incluir o código com o botão de "{}" no menu de edição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já tentou modificar o código como é mostrado abaixo:

Antes:

```
View viewFooter = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, null, false);
```

Depois:

```
View viewFooter = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, lvItens, true);
```

No site abaixo tem um artigo que mostra por que é importante usar o layoutInflater da maneira correta.
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: Ótimo artigo. Farei os testes novamente como você indicou.